# How nest ancillary command in bash arithmetic command

Tags: bash, arithmetic-expressions

I want to print the uptime for a jvm which is running on my machine. I can do that using `jcmd`. However I want to print it out in minutes. So, I tried the following:

```
bash-3.2$echo $(($(jcmd 785 VM.uptime)/60))
```

However this isn't working. I get the following error:

```
bash-3.2$ echo $(($(jcmd 785 VM.uptime)/60))
bash: 785:
1541.343 s/60: syntax error in expression (error token is ":
1541.343 s/60")
```

If I assign `$(jcmd 785 VM.uptime)` to a variable first and substitute that into the arithmetic expression, it still doesn't work. Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: What exactly does the `jcmd 785 VM.uptime` command print?

Comment: Add space after `((` and before `))`

Comment: No joy. The command prints the uptime of the jvm.

Comment: @njk2015, of course it does. But seeing that you get a syntax error when using it in an arithmetic expression, the command's output probably contains something other than just a number, right? So again, what _exactly_ does it print, and what part of that is the part you want to do arithmetic on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is not an integer, and has a character 's'. You should cut unnecessary part:

```
echo $(( $(jcmd 785 VM.uptime |sed 's/^\([[:digit:]]*\).*$/\1/')/60 ))
```

or

```
echo "scale=4;$(jcmd 785 VM.uptime |sed 's/ s//')/60" |bc
```

-- this will give you a float value.